# How do I convert text into multiple columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose now I have the following pandas data frame:

```
id text
1  A B C
2  B D
3  A D
```

And I want to get the following result:

```
id A B C D
1  1 1 1 0
2  0 1 0 1
3  1 0 0 1
```

I don't how to describe this transformation, it looks like one-hot encoding but they should be totally different.

Anyone knows how to do this transformation and what's the name of such transformation?

Answer (score 3):

Something like `str.get_dummies`

```
pd.concat([df['id'],df.text.str.get_dummies(sep=' ')],1)
Out[249]: 
   id  A  B  C  D
0   1  1  1  1  0
1   2  0  1  0  1
2   3  1  0  0  1
```

Comment: Nice use of get_dummies!

Comment: This version is better than mine. +1. My version is ignorant of `sep` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

One way is via `pd.get_dummies`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
                   'text': ['A B C', 'B D', 'A D']})

df['text'] = df['text'].str.split(' ').str.join('|')

df = df.join(df['text'].str.get_dummies()).drop('text', 1)

#    id  A  B  C  D
# 0   1  1  1  1  0
# 1   2  0  1  0  1
# 2   3  1  0  0  1
```